# What does "when using CMOS logic as the resistor..." mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does "when using CMOS logic as the resistor..." mean in the following sentence,

> This is solved **when using CMOS logic as the resistor** is replaced
> with another MOSFET that will be off so no current can flow.

?
(Source : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588489/do-mosfet-logic-gates-necessarily-need-an-n-channel-mosfet )

Does "When using CMOS logic as the resistor..." mean "This is solved when we are using CMOS logic, because the resistor is replaced with another MOSFET that will be off, so no current can flow" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct form is:

> "..when CMOS (that is) used as the resistor is replaced with another MOSFET..."

The main idea which is delivered in the sentence is that of the CMOS being replaced by the MOSFET. The "used as the resistor" clause is extra information.